# Regex matching string that doesn't contains substring

Tags: c#, regex, substring

I try to find string that doesn't contains the same substring. This is my code:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"aaa(?!.*aaa).*aaa");
var str1 = @"aaa aaa aaa";
var match = regex.Match(str1); // no
var str1 = @"aaa bbb aaa";
var match = regex.Match(str1); // yes
```

But this code doesn't work... What I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: So `"aa"` should also be rejected? It has contains two `"a"` substrings after all. If not, you need to explain it a bit better.

Comment: To help answer your question could to clarify a little more clearly what you would like a pattern to match and not match, and what values are variable in the input string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want an expression like this:

```
aaa(?:(?!aaa).)*aaa
```

`(?:(?!aaa).)*` matches strings that do not contain `aaa` (in whole or part).

You could also write it like this:

```
aaa(?:[^a]+|a(?!aa))*aaa
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect solution, I used it so ^aaa(?:(?!aaa).)*aaa$

Answer (score 0):

Im going to take a stab in the dark here and guess that you're trying to do this.

i.e.

```
`\b(\w+)\s+(?!\1\b)`
```

Matches a word `\b(\w+)`
Followed by whitespace `\s+`
Followed by a negative look-ahead for a back reference to the previously matched word. `(?!\1\b)`

```
[Test]
public void RegexTest()
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"\b(\w+)\s+(?!\1\b)");
    var str1 = @"aaa aaa aaa";
    Assert.IsFalse(regex.IsMatch(str1)); // no
    var str2 = @"aaa bbb aaa";
    Assert.IsTrue(regex.IsMatch(str2)); // yes
}
```